# Query all posts from a category then move them to another by filtering post_meta

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Posts from a category are made almost exclusively using Advanced Custom Fields and they include a start date and an end date, from custom fields. Basically, I want to query all posts from that specific category (ICO), see if the pre-start date is smaller than the current date, move the post in category x or if the start date is smaller than the current date, move it to category y. I have 2 start dates and 2 end dates via a repeater field in ACF. These posts are projects and they have a "pre" start dates and a normal start date, both with end dates.

So far, I made this and I'm not sure it's the best solution, that's why I turn to you pros :)

```
<?php

$args = array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'cat' => 13,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'category_name' => 'ico',
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$posts = $the_query->posts;

foreach($posts as $post) {

$the_id = get_the_ID();
$curtime = date('d-m-Y');

    $content = get_field('overview', $the_id);
        if($content):
           foreach ($content as $key => $content): 
           $start_date = $content['ico_time_start'];
           $end_date = $content['ico_time_end'];
           $prestart_date = $content['pre_ico_time_start'];
           $preend_date = $content['pre_ico_time_end'];
           endforeach;
        endif;

    $newicoDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($end_date));
    $newpreicoDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($preend_date));
    $currenttime = new DateTime($curtime); 
    $icoEnd   = new DateTime($newicoDate);
    $preicoEnd = new DateTime($newpreicoDate);

    if ($preicoEnd < $currenttime) : wp_set_post_categories( $the_id, array( 13, 15 ) ); endif;
    if ($icoEnd < $currenttime) : wp_set_post_categories( $the_id, array( 13, 16 ) ); endif;
}
?>
```

I want to to be able to launch this as cron (not wp cron) once or twice per day to check all posts from the category and move them if needed.

Comment: have you created any linux cron jobs in the past? you can add a php script to run as a linux cron job.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work in your case

```
# crontab -e
00 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/user/yourscript.php
```

First from the Linux command line issue

```
crontab -e
```

in the fist line, enter the followiong

```
00 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/user/yourscript.php
```

the first set of numbers indicate the timing of the cron job.